# Ambiguous column name in update's where statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I have one result table and two source tables. One source have same column name for key as result table, and second one have slightly different (same values, just different column name).
So if i use code as:

```
--Works
Update new_table set new_column_1 = source_column_1
from new_table t0
Left join source_table_1 t1 
    On t0.key_column = t1.id_column
Where key_column = t0.key_column

--Don't
Update new_table set new_column_2 = source_column_2
from new_table t0
Left join source_table_2 t1 
    On t0.key_column = t1.key_column
Where key_column = t0.key_column
```

2nd example would give me "Ambiguous column name" error in Where statement. (1st key_column should belong to update destination, 2nd to update source)

I manage around that problem by wrapping source for update into subquery which would rename key column into something else, but i'm curious why that happens in a first place. How come that key names for join make effect on where clause?

Comment: Why don't you use the alias t1? It probably work because source table 1 doesn't have a key_column but table 2 does. In Q2, there is no way to know if the 1st key_column belongs to t0 or t1 without using the alias.

Comment: i'm not sure if you can assign allias for table that is destination of update, and attempt to do Where new_table.key_column = t0.key_column gives me "Unable to bound multipart identifier"

Answer (score 2):

You must use the alias since both table have a column named key_column.

This query should work:

```
Update t0 set new_column_2 = t1.source_column_2 -- or t0.source_column_2?
from new_table t0
Left join source_table_2 t1 
    On t0.key_column = t1.key_column
Where t1.key_column = t0.key_column
```

The alias will replace the table name between update and set.

But the where clause does not seem necessary. It is identical to the ON clause. A INNER JOIN would be more appropriate here.